# Pyomo - lopping an objective function over an index?

Tags: python, pyomo

I want to loop an objective function on an index. Let's say that I have the following dataframe:

| index_i | index_j | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10400 | Mexico | 23 |
| 10400 | Guatemala | 44 |
| 10600 | Mexico | 25 |
| 10600 | Guatemala | 30 |

I want to do something like this:

```
for i in model.i:
         model.obj = Objective(sum(x[i,j] for j in model.j), maximize)
         ...
         results = opt.solve(model)
```

I want to do the loop directly in the objective function or solve, because I don't want to build i-times the model variables and parameters (i.e., looping the opt model i-times).

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have it correct in the first instance.  It isn't clear what you are trying to avoid...  ?  Realize all this is doing is constructing an expression to hand to the model.  It isn't "looping" as it solves, if that is your concern.

Your second effort, looping over i, will create a new obj for each value of i and then solve with that specific value *only*.  Is that what you intend?

For example:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

m = ConcreteModel()

# SETS
m.I = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])
m.J = Set(initialize=list('ABC'))

# VARIABLES
m.x = Var(m.I, m.J, domain=Binary)

# GOOD OBJ
m.obj1 = Objective(expr=sum(m.x[i,j] for i in m.I for j in m.J))

# BAD OBJ!!  DON'T DO THIS
for i in m.I:
    m.obj2 = Objective(expr=sum(m.x[i,j] for j in m.J))


m.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
3 Set Declarations
    I : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
    J : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'A', 'B', 'C'}
    x_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    I*J :    9 : {(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'A'), (3, 'B'), (3, 'C')}

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=9, Index=x_index
        Key      : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (1, 'A') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (1, 'B') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (1, 'C') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (2, 'A') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (2, 'B') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (2, 'C') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (3, 'A') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (3, 'B') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (3, 'C') :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary

2 Objective Declarations
    obj1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : x[1,A] + x[1,B] + x[1,C] + x[2,A] + x[2,B] + x[2,C] + x[3,A] + x[3,B] + x[3,C]
    obj2 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : x[3,A] + x[3,B] + x[3,C]

6 Declarations: I J x_index x obj1 obj2
```

Note in the 2nd obj, it is overwriting itself in the loop and only captures the last value of `i` (3).

If this isn't what you were asking about, edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Hi AirSquid. Thanks for your reply! My issue is that I have a lot of i entries, and I am not really optimizing for the aggregate of all the i, but for each i. So, yes, what I want to do is what you said.   "Your second effort, looping over i, will create a new obj for each value of i and then solve with that specific value only. Is that what you intend?"  Sorry for not being so clear.

Comment: OK.  Good.  So is there still a question?

Comment: Yes. How can you do the looping without having to define the Variables and Parameters over and over?

Comment: Well, right now you don't appear to be doing that....  You are just over-writing your OBJ function in the loop and then solving, assuming that all your variables and parameters are established before your `for i in ...` statement.  That seems pretty efficient.  You could create a bunch of OBJ statements all at once and activate/deactivate them, but that seems like a pain and I'm not sure if it is any more efficient.